# What Calculation can I use to count the number of records per day over a timeline?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm wanting to show the difference between Connections and Disconnects over a timeline. If I can create a measure that stores the number of connects or disconnects each day I can subtract them from each other to get the difference.

For an example I'm counting how many records have the same disconnect date. I've tried working with the count function but I'm not sure how to count the number of records for each day.

At this point I'm not sure I have meaningful code to share. :(

A solution would hopefully be able to produce a table that shows the connect or disconnect date along with how many records have that same date.

The meaningful fields would be the Acct and the Disc_dt or Conn_dt.
All accounts will have a connect date but may not have a disconnect date.

ex.

```
DATE    -    COUNT
01/01/2018 - 3
02/01/2018 - 5
03/01/2018 - 4
```

Comment: Please provide your source data and what you want as result so we can better understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the following question:

[How to calculate daily population in DAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55961210/how-to-calculate-daily-population-in-dax)

It will give you a solution you can use also if I understand you correct.