# How to calculate daily population in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I'm trying to calculate the daily population of patients at our center for any given date using the patient's booking date (start date) and their release date -- using DAX and Power Pivot. I'm planning on using it in PowerBI eventually.

I've tried the formula below. I'm not getting any errors, but when I go to create a pivot table/chart in excel, I'm not getting the correct output.

I'm only using two tables: 1) a main table with the patient data and 2) a date table (calendar) and have established a relationship between the two tables.

The booking table has Patient ID, Booking Date, Release Date columns. I'd like to be able to create a graph showing the total population by day taking both dates into consideration.

```
DailyPop :=
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( Patients ),
    FILTER (
        Patients,
        AND (
            Patients[Booking Date] > MIN ( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
            Patients[Release Date] < MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi Eric & welcome to StackOverflow! Have you marked the Date table as a DATE dimension? Sometimes that's all it takes

Comment: Yep, it was marked as a date dimension!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an extra column on your date table:

```
PatientCount:= SUMX(Patients,IF(Patients[Booking Date]<='Calendar'[Date] && Patients[Release Date]>='Calendar'[Date],1,0))
```

Comment: Thank you. This works.  Can you tell me how to slice this by gender, provider, or other columns in the patient table?

Comment: You are welcome, please mark as answered and ask new question. This keeps stackoverflow usable..